# Calling C code from C# where the C code is in a .lib

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2015

I have some C code that I want to call from C#. I have read several posts but they are all for .DLL's. My C code is in .LIB's. Is there a way?

If so can you give a brief example?

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Give you a guide is a little bit complicated. BTW what you need is to make a wrapper dll. This wrapper must link the lib file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found out on another forum that I must do just that. I have made that change.